# Ворона и воронка

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Ворона и воронка - слова, вроде бы, не имеющие ничего общего по смыслу, но одновременно являющиеся однокоренными и родственными. А почему так? Какая связь между ними?
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Шанского:

Ворона - общеславянское слово, образовано от звукоподражательного "вър", родственное слово - ворковать.

Воронка - также общеславянское слово от "vorna" - дыра, отверстие.Существует диалектный глагола "верать" - совать, прятать, из этого следует, что воронка- это место, где можно прятаться.

В словаре Черных высказывается предположение о связи воронки со словами "вереница, вериги" c и.-е. корнем ver - связывать, присоединять. В частности, существует диалектное слово "веренька" - рыболовная коробка с узким входным отверстием.

А вот само слово "отверстие" этимологически с воронкой не связано, является исконно русским и соотносится с глаголом "отъвьрсти" - открыть.